# Sitecollection Web Analytics Reports 

Tags: web-analytics, out-of-the-box

Is there any way to use the 'SiteCollection WebAnalytics Reports', (which gives a beautiful bar charts for Top Visitors and some more catagories) on our own subsites. We want to make them available for some targeted users of our site. The available Web Analytics Webpart, is not providing all those Traffic, Summary reports. (Path of report page-- http://server:port/_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=SummaryReport&l=sc)
I know the table from which it is getting usage data out of content database.

I dont know Which web part was used.  Please share your knowledge in this.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few commercial solutions available for SharePoint monitoring & reporting -

[AvePoint SharePoint Reporting suite (includes a free SP monitor)](http://www.avepoint.com/SharePoint-reporting-software/)

[Unilytics Mergence for SP Reporting](http://unilytics.com/products/mergence/)

[HarePoint Analytics for SP](http://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointAnalyticsForSharePoint/Default.aspx)

[Vyapin Admin Report Kit for SharePoint 2010](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010/arksp/sharepoint-2010-reports.htm)

[Axceler ControlPoint for SharePoint Administration](http://www.axceler.com/Products/ControlPoint.aspx)

CAVEAT: I do not work for the above companies but have evaluated some of their products.